# How can i get the fastest perfomance on client system?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

How can i get fastest performance? I always use calculation on client application than making it in procedures. I got a table of about 10,000 rows to evaluate. The database is in a hosting web server and i've been reading all the rows and displaying in a datagrid in my application.

So on my way reading columns 'ProductPrice' and 'ProductQty', I can calculate the ProductPrice * Qty and store it in another column within application, considering less data to be streamed over.

Which of the following would be faster?

```
SqlCommand sqlCmdTxt = new SqlCommand(conn);
SqlDataReader sqlRead;

sqlCmdTxt.commandText = "Select ProductPrice, ProductQty, ProductPrice * ProductQty As Total From Stock";
sqlRead = sqlCmdTxt.ExecuteReader();
while (
sqlRead.Read()) {
    double price = sqlRead.GetDouble(0);
    double qty = sqlRead.GetDouble(1);
    double sum = price * qty;

    dataGridView.rows.add (new object[] {price, qty, sum});
}
```

or

```
SqlCommand sqlCmdTxt = new SqlCommand(conn);
DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand("Select ProductPrice, ProductQty, ProductPrice * ProductQty As Total From Stock"
    , conn)).Fill(dSet, "StockList");
dataGridView.DataSource = dSet.Tables["StockList"].DefaultView;
```

Comment: You are answering the question kind of yourself, you noticed a slight speed increase with your sp-approach, but are not sure. Why should it be easier for us to test it than it is for you? If you are not sure if it REALLY is faster, repeat the test several times (also look for external factors/programms running parallely etc.). Then you should be quite sure, then just produce some test data in which you blow up the size of your database (easily done with a cross join) and see if the speed increase becomes more obvious. Voilà

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The calculation itself is likely to be insignificant (whether done on server or client). What tends to be much more significant is the physical data retrieval (query execution plan, caching, clustering, partitioning etc.) and the transfer of that data from server to client.

In this particular case, you are using the same query in both cases, so I'd expect that doing the calculation client-side will simply add (very little) time to the time that was necessary for the query itself in any case.

However, if you had...

```
Select ProductPrice, ProductQty From Stock
```

...versus...

```
Select ProductPrice * ProductQty As Total From Stock
```

...I'd expect the second to be slightly faster: transferring (from server to client) a bunch of larger 2-field tuples (for the first query) is likely to take more time than transferring the same number of smaller 1-field tuples (for the second query). In addition to that, it would eat-up more of the available network bandwidth, affecting other concurrent clients.

And if you ever need to filter<sup>1</sup> the data in any way, using server-side `WHERE` is likely to be *much* faster than fetching all the rows to the client just to discard most of the rows there. If you are interested in the topic of database performance, I warmly recommend taking a look at: [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)

Recommendations:

- Your "default" position should be to do as much as practically possible on the server.
- If in doubt, don't guess, instead **measure** on representative amounts of data (50000 rows hardly qualifies as "big" in database terms).

---

<sup>1</sup> Or aggregate (`SUM`, `AVG`, `MAX`...) or `JOIN` etc...

Answer (score 3):

My opinion is to do all calculations on the server - it is definitely faster.

If you use a slower machine for SQL Server than you can get worse results running on the server. In the case where you're running it on the same machine I prefer to use SQL Server.

Comment: From your case depends on what you wont to do. If you iterate results in c# than is beter to do calculation from c# code, becouse you have to itearate them anyway and one calculation will not made some time diference. But if you bind your data to some Grid than is better to calculate from sql.

Comment: @KalanjDjordjeDjordje, do you have any reference for that or is it just your opinion? There is no defacto best practice. It always depends on a number of factors.

Answer (score 1):

Generally a stored procedure is better - not only does it abstract the underlying DB schema from the client (giving you more of an API approach to the data tier), but it allows the SQL Engine to manipulate the data and return just the result to you.

As Branko said, the reduced data transfer can be significant, but also look at your code: not only are you performing the same old multiply operation, but you're also running the client driver fetch and converting the value to a double. This means you not only fetch the data from the DB, pop it into a buffer, transfer that buffer to the client, but you then read the buffered data to your own string and then convert it. All those little layers of code and buffer manipulation can add up, especially as you don't know what kind of temporary buffers are created inside the sql read calls to provide you with the values.

Its also entirely possible the sql stored procedure notices that you're going to convert the data to double and provides a hidden double storage with the data pre-converted for you; and there's also a lot of caching that it can provide too if it knows what you want (and SPs always know as you tell it), so the 2nd time you hit that SP, it simply returns the unchanged data's previous result.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your code in C# is going to be faster since there is less data to transfer between the SQL engine and your application. With 50K rows this is not very important but with far bigger rows & tables saving on the transfer cost, which might be over a slow network, can make a significant difference.

The second time this SQL is run on your server, SQL may have cached the results. So it might be faster (fewer calculations) but still you will get a transfer cost.

Comment: @Sayka The performance cannot be "added later", you have to plan for it in advance. Even if you don't have a network between server and client, there is still the "transfer cost" (possibly of inter-process communication, depending on DBMS), and the "physical retrieval" aspect is unaffected at any rate. If you always fetch whole tables there may well be no significant difference, but then you are not using the database as it is supposed to be used.

Comment: @Sayka BTW, if you only need a local database, perhaps SQL Server should not be your first choice? Consider an embedded database such as SQL Server Compact Edition or SQLite.